# Nautilus freezing issues

Tags: nautilus

Using 18.04.5 LTS, and very new to this.

I was copying rather large files (800+ images) when Nautilus froze so bad that I couldn't access the GNOME terminal using keyboard shortcuts. I had to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> to access a text terminal to kill Nautilus. Ever since then as soon as I open Nautilus it freezes (though I can use `kill` or `killall` to end the process and it doesn't freeze up bad enough that I need to access a text terminal). Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I am not sure what happened but there's probably something wrong with the current user's configuration. Can you try with a newly created Ubuntu user?